# Copy all tables from a database to another server database

Tags: mysql, ssh

I have a database named db_x on xx.xx.xx.xx server.
I want to move all the tables of this database ( db_x ) to another database(db_y) which is on different server(yy.yy.yy.yy).

Can I do using terminal by connecting to ssh?

Please help me.

Comment: yes, you can do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a dump (backup) of db_x and import it into db_y. This can be done in one step:

```
mysqldump -u... -p... -h xx.xx.xx.xx db_x | mysql -u... -p... -h yy.yy.yy.yy db_y
```

**Update**

Note that this solution only works if you can connect to both of your DBs from your local PC.

As @BerndBuffen stated in the comments, it is usually faster in 2 steps and you can also avoid the necessity to have DB access from localhost:

```
# go to X server and make the dump there:
ssh xx.xx.xx.xx
mysqldump -u ... -p... db_x | gzip > db_x.sql.gz
```

Copy the file db_x.sql.gz to the other server. If necessary copy it to localhost first and from there to server yy.yy.yy.yy.
Make sure the database `db_y` is already created on server Y.

```
# go to Y server and import the dump there:
ssh yy.yy.yy.yy
gzip -dc db_x.sql.gz | mysql -u ... -p... db_y
```

Whether the `-h xx.xx.xx.xx` and/or `-h yy.yy.yy.yy` switches are needed when you are already connected to the respective servers (via ssh)
depends on your setup.

Comment: but normaly its faster in 2 steps mysqldump -u... -p... -h xx.xx.xx.xx db_x | gzip > db_x.sql.gz  and then scp to the other server and import

Comment: @BerndBuffen Really? How comes? Network I/O? Well, actually I would do it in 2 steps because then it's easier to get the error messages (if there are any) apart.

Comment: @BerndBuffen Ahh, I see. The dump files are really zip friendly.

Comment: yes - network traffic. If you do it in one step you can use a -C option to compress the network traffic and make sure that you have create a database db_y before you can import. in the dump is no create database included

Comment: @BerndBuffen If you change the dump to `mysqldump -u... -p... -h xx.xx.xx.xx --databases db_x` then there is.

Comment: 100% OK, but when you dump db_x with --ddatabases you cant do this mysql -u.. -p... -h...... db_y < dump.sql - there is a crete database db_x in the dumpfile and they want to import it into db_y

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106050/discussion-between-bernd-buffen-and-perl-dog).